# Creating valuse resource file

Tags: android

What is " source set " mean in this window and what is the difference between source set types

[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build#sourcesets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [document](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants):

> Android Studio creates the main/source set and directories for
> everything you want to share between all your build variants. However,
> you can create new source sets to control exactly what files Gradle
> compiles and packages for specific build types, product flavors (and
> combinations of product flavors when using flavor dimensions), and
> build variants. For example, you can define basic functionality in the
> main/ source set and use product flavor source sets to change the
> branding of your app for different clients, or include special
> permissions and logging functionality only for build variants that use
> the debug build type.
>
> Gradle expects you to organize source set files and directories a
> certain way, similar to the main/ source set. For example, Gradle
> expects Java class files that are specific to your "debug" build type
> to be located in the src/debug/java/ directory.